# Manual entry of mac address in terminal of osx, getting permission denied

Tags: osx-leopard

Hi there I'm trying to set my mac address using the terminal as for some reason it's been set to all zeros, I have the address and know the correct commands but I keep getting permision denied message

Answer (score 1):

In principle the command should be some variant on the theme of:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

in Mac OS prior to 10.7, with various interface names etc, in use. It seems that you may need to disassociate from the wireless network first, but leave the wireless on -- some manage this by typing 'sudo airport -z' first, whilst there are various other workarounds suggested in the links below. There are various hints about MAC address spoofing on [OSX daily](http://osxdaily.com/2008/01/17/how-to-spoof-your-mac-address-in-mac-os-x/) and on [this thread](http://www.cneophytou.com/2008/01/19/spoofing-leopards-mac-address/).

As regards 'permission denied' errors - did you prefix the commands with 'sudo'?

Comment: Depending on which version of OS X you're using, you might have to change `en0` to the `en1` interface, but otherwise, looks good!